# BouncyCastleJsseProvider: Client raised fatal(2) internal_error(80) alert: Failed to read record

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I have run into an issue developing a HTTP client with the use of BouncyCastle libraries.
Target versions (but the error is also reproducible in **Java 1.8.0_91** with the same version of BouncyCastle.)

- JRE 1.6.0_45-b06
- BouncyCastle jdk15to18 167 (bcprov-jdk15to18-167.jar, bcpkix-jdk15to18-167.jar, bctls-jdk15to18-167.jar)

HTTPClient code:

```
            String strURL = "https://www.<WEBSITE>.com";
            // CODE to set default TrustStore, KeyStore to be used

            // setup BC as SecurityProvider and SSLSocketFactoryProvider
/*
            Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
            Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 2);
            Security.setProperty("ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm", "PKIX");
            Security.setProperty("ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm", "PKIX");  
            Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
            System.setProperty("jdk.tls.trustNameService", "true");
*/
            URL url = new URL( strURL );
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            
            InputStream is = null;
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println("OK");
                is = conn.getInputStream();
            } else if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
                is = conn.getErrorStream();
            } else  {
                System.out.println( conn.getResponseCode() );
                System.out.println( conn.getResponseMessage() );
            }
        
            if (is != null) {  
                System.out.println( readFullyAsString(is, "UTF-8") );
            }
            conn.disconnect();
```

Accessing data on a website with TLS 1.2 **without client_auth** works fine (there are some issues with specific sites that return handshake_failure(40), but luckily not in our case). But when client_auth is required the code fails with the following (*a little cryptic*) error:

```
nov. 27, 2020 5:23:10 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient notifyAlertRaised
WARNING: Client raised fatal(2) internal_error(80) alert: Failed to read record
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.fillTo(RecordStream.java:429)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.readHeader(RecordStream.java:468)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(RecordStream.java:201)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(TlsProtocol.java:768)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.readApplicationData(TlsProtocol.java:731)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect$AppDataInput.read(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:603)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at HttpsClient.main(HttpsClient.java:109)

nov. 27, 2020 5:23:10 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient notifyAlertRaised
WARNING: Client raised fatal(2) internal_error(80) alert: Failed to read record
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.fillTo(RecordStream.java:429)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.readHeader(RecordStream.java:468)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(RecordStream.java:201)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(TlsProtocol.java:768)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.readApplicationData(TlsProtocol.java:731)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect$AppDataInput.read(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:603)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at HttpsClient.main(HttpsClient.java:109)

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.fillTo(RecordStream.java:429)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream$Record.readHeader(RecordStream.java:468)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(RecordStream.java:201)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(TlsProtocol.java:768)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.readApplicationData(TlsProtocol.java:731)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect$AppDataInput.read(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:603)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at HttpsClient.main(HttpsClient.java:109)
```

As expected the code runs just fine in Java 1.8 without BC as Security Provider ... but in Java 1.6 BC is needed for TLS 1.2 support.

I looked at the packets with Wireshark, but I don't have enough knowledge to analyze what's happening (failing) with the SSL handshake operation with the server.

What am I missing here? Or it's just a known limitation of BC?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: 80 is internal_error and could be almost anything, including something perfectly legal. Best approach is to find out from the server log(s) what it thinks the problem is, perhaps after setting 'detail' or 'debug' logging or similar. Next best is to find out what SSL/TLS implementation and data the server uses and replicate it in a controlled environment. Last would be to obtain detailed TLS knowledge and look at the Bouncy protocol messages as compared to standard-JSSE, and perhaps other working client(s), to see what is different even if not illegal or wrong.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for your ideas: we'll try to replicate it in our controlled environment as we don't have access to the server. I'll post our findings (and hopefully solution)

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research and testing (we set up our own dev environment that replicated the endpoint, we were trying to connect to with client cert) we have found a solution (*posted below*) that works for us in our dev environment, but couldn't be configured on the endpoint. That's why we went to plan B - [TLS termination proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy) and it worked like a charm in our case, when we didn't have control of the server environment.

**Solution for IIS**

In our case the web service requiring client auth was running on Microsoft IIS. As stated "*Unfortunately our TLS libraries do not support renegotiation (and we do not plan to add it, although there are corresponding TLS 1.3 features that we will).*" in this open issue (https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/593). After reading the IIS documentation and some testing we successfully configured the environment in a way that TLS sessions could be established with BC TLS lib:

Step 1:

- Create an IIS site with default settings
- Run [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) with the "Best practices" template:
  [image: ~b390679]
  [image: ~b433872]
  [image: ~b338486]

Step 2:

- Enable SSLAlwaysNegoClientCert

Save the following text to a file called "Enable_SSL_Renegotiate.js"

```
var vdirObj=GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3svc/1");
// replace 1 on this line with the number of the web site you wish to configure
WScript.Echo("Value of SSLAlwaysNegoClientCert Before: " + vdirObj.SSLAlwaysNegoClientCert);
vdirObj.Put("SSLAlwaysNegoClientCert", true);
vdirObj.SetInfo();
WScript.Echo("Value of SSLAlwaysNegoClientCert After: " + vdirObj.SSLAlwaysNegoClientCert);
```

Run the following command from an elevated / administrator command prompt:

```
cscript.exe enable_ssl_renegotiate.js
```

*I posted the same answer on BouncyCastle Github - [#847](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/847)*